# Why so few GPU kernels for the sparse operation in tensorflow?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, gpu

In my multi-GPU tensorflow (1.13) training, some sparse-related operations consume a considerable amount of time. In the timeline, I found that these sparse operations can only be performed on the CPU, which have no GPU kernel support, and resulting in frequent memory copies.

e.g.

[image]

As shown above, SparseFillEmptyRows and SparseSegmentSum take up most of the CPU time and cause a large number of memory copies (DtoH && HtoD). If these two ops can be moved to GPU, I think there can be a big performance improvement.

I want to know what is the reason behind it. Is it simply that no one is developing it? Or does the sparse operation perform poorly on the GPU?